# How to use field from map query

Tags: apex, map

```java
for (Id sourceObjectId : sObjectsFromDbCloned.keySet()) {
    SObject sObjectFromDbCloned = sObjectsFromDbCloned.get(sourceObjectId);
    if (sObjectFromDbCloned.Id != null) {
        clonedIds.put(sourceObjectId, sObjectFromDbCloned.Id);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '========2.1- Cloning cart [' + sourceObjectId + '] to [' + sObjectFromDbCloned.Id + ']');
        Map<Id, CameleonCPQ__QxQuote__c> q = new Map<Id, CameleonCPQ__QxQuote__c>([
                SELECT
                        Id,
                        Name,
                        CameleonCPQ__ExternalQuoteId__c
                FROM CameleonCPQ__QxQuote__c
                WHERE Id IN :new String[]{sourceObjectId, sObjectFromDbCloned.Id, actionName}
        ]);
        System.debug('QuotexQuery ' + q);
    }
}
```

From this `q` map, I am trying store value of field name into `desp` variable,

```
String desp = q.Name;
```

But it gives me error variable doesn't exist.

Could you please guide me? How should I achieve this using this map query itself?

Comment: You're going to have to use `.get(key)` on the map, with the key in this case being the ID of the `CameleonCPQ__QxQuote__c` record you want to retrieve as `q` is a collection. From there you can absolutely use `.Name`. Also, a bit unrelated, but don't use dml statements inside a loop, in this case a SOQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Map and trying to get the value from it as if it is an SObject variable. First, retrieve the SObject by doing `CameleonCPQ__QxQuote__c cpq = q.get(key)`; and then do `String desp = cpq.Name`.